# Macro to sort Alphabatical + Numbers with special cases

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, vba

I have a hard time sorting something out, I need for my workspace.

```
TBK1872(2)
TKP1880
TKP1898(2)+1
TKP190
TKP1911
TKP2006-1
TKP2103(2)
TKP2195(2)+1
TKP310(2)
TKP32
TKP32+1
TKQ1267
TKQ13
TKQ138(2)
```

These are signatures I need to order in a specific way.

First of all, these signatures should be ordered, that they are in an alphabetic order.
There are those cases, where it can happen that there are four letters instead of three.
Those should come after the three letters

Example : `TQL` then after that the for letters like `TQLA` then `TQLB` and so on...

Then the numbers should be sorted after how short they are so 2 numbers then three numbers then for numbers not like the normal sort of:

```
TKP310(2)
TKP32
TKP32+1
TKQ1267
TKQ13
```

where numbers are sorted on high of the second number.

After that there are those special cases where an (2) or +1 or a combination of both is happening.
These should be sorted after the number in the brackets and then after the +1 count beginning from 1

Is it anyway possible writing an sorting algorithm for that?
Could someone help me ?
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [Why is 'Can someone help me?' not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Split your original string into the different sections, and sort on each section in the priority order.  It might be easier to figure out what you are trying to do with an example of source data, results when you try to sort it,  and your expected results.   You can do the splitting using excel worksheet functions, or perhaps a VBA Regular Expression type function, for both of which there are plenty of examples.

Comment: If the obvious misnomer *'Could someone help me ?'* is removed, the only remaining inquiry is *'Is it anyway possible writing an sorting algorithm for that?'* The answer to that is a qualified **yes**; in other words, *yes* but not given the current state of your question. You've provided examples of what not to do but haven't offered any example of what is correct. Your criteria narrative is open to some interpretation and could be construed as contradicting itself in places.

Comment: The shortest and most expedient method to convey your expectations is to provide unsorted data that includes all possible variances to be addressed and supplement that with a demonstration of expected results. Don't let the expected results contradict your narrative; people reading your question can generally make more sense from sample data and expected results than several paragraphs describing same. If you can provide what is described above, assistance could be offered.

Comment: This is not a game of 20 Questions. If you endeavor to improve your question through an [edit], please do so with the following mantra in mind. To wit: *How can I reword and provide additional data to my question where the first response from me after receiving an answer is **not** going to start with 'But what if ...'?*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a complicated **custom sort order** to sort in an odd (or "special") order, by **importing a list** of all the values in the order that you want it.

If the list only contains a few items, it's probably quicker to enter the list into the custom sort dialog manually.

---

## Sort data using a custom list

With built-in custom lists, you can sort data —either by days of the week or months of the year. Optionally, you can create your own custom lists to sort by any other characteristic that doesn’t sort well alphabetically—such as high, medium, and low—or S, M, L, XL.

For example, with custom lists you could sort this worksheet by delivery (month) or by priority.

[image: Sample table]

For example, to sort by days of the week or months of the year with a built-in custom list, you do the following:

1. Select the columns you want to sort.
   *For the best results, each column should have headings.*
2. On the ribbon, Click **Data** > **Sort**:

   [image: Sort button]
3. In the **Sort** dialog box, in the **Sort** by box, *select the column* you want to sort by:

   [image: Sort by the delivery column]
4. From the **Order** dropdown, select **Custom List**:

   [image: Sort dialog box]
5. In the **Custom Lists** tab, select the list you want, and then click **OK** to sort the worksheet:

   [image: Custom lists dialog box]

---

## Create your own custom list

1. In a column of a worksheet, enter the values to sort by. Arrange them in the order that you want to define the sort order—from top to bottom. For example:

   [image: Custom list example]
2. Select the cells in that list column, and then click **File** > **Options** > **Advanced**.
3. Under **General**, click **Edit Custom Lists**.
4. In the **Custom Lists** box, click ***Import***:

   [image: Import a custom list]

---

- *Further examples, information and resources can be found at [**the source**](https://support.office.com/article/sort-data-using-a-custom-list-def8ff2b-681a-4fc3-9bd2-a06455c379e1).*